# Dynamically add destination fields to migration - importing data when fields on destination entity are not know

Tags: entities, migrations, importing-exporting, 8

I am trying to import content from JSON from an API call. This API call has different source data depending on what the call is.

For my migration from this JSON, there are set fields that I have coded into the YAML migration file under the process section. The issue I am running into is, some of the fields change, so I need a way to dynamically add these fields to the process section if they exists. Is this possible with Migration?

I think there must be some way to do if with derivers, but I am struggling at how to implement this.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried [skip_on_empty](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21migrate%21src%21Plugin%21migrate%21process%21SkipOnEmpty.php/class/SkipOnEmpty/8.6.x) before going the code route?

Comment: What do you mean by *some of the fields change*?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to implement something similar https://www.webomelette.com/dynamic-migrations-using-templates-drupal-8. This is a good example of dynamic migration.